# LTL Proofs (next A <-> A atnext True)

Tags: logic

I don't know if this is the correct place for this, but I was reading [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnjx4arim9qxct4/ch3.pdf): [image: page 69.]

and I don't fully understand how they are forming these proofs. For example, I was trying to follow Proof of (Tb5) (towards the top of p. 69) but I don't fully understand how they are making the jumps that they do. Maybe I don't understand the process of doing these proofs, but I can't really find anything with a better description online.

I tried working through the "trivial" proof of (Tb8) on the bottom of p. 69, but I don't know where to go after writing the definition of atnext.

Can someone explain to me what is going on in plain English? Any suggestions on reading to understand proofs like this?

Comment: Your link seems to be dead.

Comment: Should work now!

Comment: I would suggest that you either type up the relevant sections or attach them as images here if it's too long. There's a chance that the link will drop again and many people here do not like to visit external links.

Comment: Updated again. Thanks!